# Django-Filter: ModelChoiceFilter using queryset related to the current user

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using Django-Filter library.

I have 2 models, `Listing` and `ListingReview`. I would like to be able to create a filter for the ListingReview model, so that people can select which Listing they want to see reviews for.

```
# models.py:
class Listing(models.Model):
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='listings', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ListingReview(models.Model)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='listing_reviews') 


# filters.py

def listings(request):
    # if request is None:
    #     return Listing.objects.none()
    return Listing.objects.filter(posted_by=request.user)


class ListingReviewFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    listing = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        name='listing', lookup_expr='isnull',
        empty_label='All listings',
        queryset=listings,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ListingReview
        fields = ['listing']
```

However, I don't understand why `request is None`, I get:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

**What I need:**
For a given `user`, find the associated Listings using: `Listing.objects.filter(posted_by=user)` and pass it to the `queryset` parameter in the filter e.g. dynamically define the queryset based on current user. Since every user owns a different set of listings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you sent parameter `user` in your request from client, when you try to call this method?

Comment: If you mean parameter `?user=1` in the  browser, the no I didn't. But I don't want to specify it, because I want it to be done for the `request.user`.

Comment: Request object has attribute 'META', this is also a dictionary, that containing all available HTTP headers, such as 'REMOTE_USER' (The user authenticated by the Web server, if any). Try to use request.META.REMOTE_USER, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a custom filter [`method`](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html?highlight=method#customize-filtering-with-filter-method)

```
class ListingReviewFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    listing = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        name='listing',
        lookup_expr='isnull',
        empty_label='All listings',
        queryset=Listing.objects.all(),
        method='filter_listing',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ListingReview
        fields = ['listing']

   def filter_listing(self, queryset, name, value):
       return queryset.filter(posted_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I did, but `self` is not defined there - I get unresolved reference.

Comment: Now it returns all listings in the filter, but the users have all listings, even the ones not posted by them. I think the `queryset` is not actually filtered properly in the end. For the test, I had 2 users (1 with 10 listings and other with 0) and the filter showed the same 10 listings to both.